# Dozer Map DTO Mapping

Tags: java, dozer

I have a little "Object":

```
Map<Integer, Map<WeekDay, Map<String, Data>>> obj
```

and I want to Map it to:

```
Map<Integer, Map<WeekDay, Map<String, DataDto>>> returnObj
```

how can I achive this?

The way I wanted to use was this one:

```
map(schedule, Map<Integer.class, Map<WeekDay.class, Map<String.class, DataDto.class>>>);
```

but at the "Map" I am stuck, becuase I can't add a .class behind them and in this state it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to simplify your Map if possible:

```
class A {
    WeekDay weekDay;
    String str;
    Data obj;
}

Map<Integer, A> map = ...;
Iterables.transform(map.values(), new Function<Data, DataDto>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(String input) {
                return ...;
            }
        });
```

or you can put it inside your class:

```
class Dictionary {
    Map<Integer, Map<WeekDay, Map<String, Data>>> obj;

    getDataDto(Integer key, Weekday weekDay, String str) {
        final Data data = obj.get(key).get(weekDay).get(str);
        return (new Function<Data, DataDto>() {
            ...
        }).apply(data);
    }
}
```

Think about operations you are going to use over your data structure and come up with the proper class. Your nested map doesn't look okay.

Comment: Well the map represents a table to display it on a web site with the outer map representing the "row headings" the second on the "column headings" and the third one the real table cells, and because the way a html table is generated, the format itself seems to be ok for me.

Comment: If you don't use a lookup operation then you don't need a map. Why don't you switch to something like `class Table {
 List<Heading> hs;
 List<Row> rows;
}

class Row {
 List<Cell> cells;
}`

Comment: We restructured the code to get different classes, but nevertheless, the dozer mapper can't map a Map<String, List<Data>> to Map<String, List<DataDto>>